# Use Flink to call arangodb Java driver API to insert data into arangodb and report error err 'transaction ID already used'

Tags: apache-flink, arangodb

Use Flink to call arangodb Java driver API to insert data into arangodb and report error err 'transaction ID already used'

```
Caused by: TimerException{com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 500, Error: 1590 - AQL: error, cluster node: 'PRMR-c338134b-023c-438d-b672-d5f954c2882c', endpoint: 'tcp://192.168.2.137:8530', error: 'transaction ID already used' (while optimizing plan)}
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SystemProcessingTimeService$TriggerTask.run(SystemProcessingTimeService.java:284)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 500, Error: 1590 - AQL: error, cluster node: 'PRMR-c338134b-023c-438d-b672-d5f954c2882c', endpoint: 'tcp://xxx:8530', error: 'transaction ID already used' (while optimizing plan)
    at com.arangodb.internal.util.ResponseUtils.checkError(ResponseUtils.java:53)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.checkError(VstCommunication.java:149)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:128)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:42)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.execute(VstCommunication.java:132)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstProtocol.execute(VstProtocol.java:47)
    at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:71)
    at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:53)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is too little information to help you. What is your flink version? How is your topology looking? When is the error occurring? Is any data written at all?

Comment: The Flink version is 1.9.1, and the arangodb version is 3.5.0. This error is very rare when writing to the arangodb through the Flink write point and edge. It has been encountered twice so far and can be written very smoothly in other times. I suspect the problem is caused by concurrent write, but I test concurrent write with test code, no problem

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/10794) in arangodb and should be resolved in later versions.